# Can typedef names be used to declare or define constructors?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

#### Standardese:

[class.ctor] 12.1/1 says

> A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor. The syntax uses:
>
> — an optional *decl-specifier-seq* in which each *decl-specifier* is either a *function-specifier* or **constexpr**,
>
> — the constructor’s class name, and
>
> — a parameter list
>
> in that order.

[class.name] 9.1/4 says

> A *typedef-name* (7.1.3) that names a class type, or a cv-qualified
> version thereof, is also a *class-name*. If a *typedef-name* that names a
> cv-qualified class type is used where a *class-name* is required, the
> cv-qualifiers are ignored. A *typedef-name* shall not be used as the
> *identifier* in a *class-head*.

Also [expr.prim.general] 5.1.1/8 says

> Where *class-name* :: *class-name* is used, and the two class-names refer
> to the same class, this notation names the constructor (12.1).

---

#### Application:

This seems to me to say that declaring a constructor should be allowed using typedef names (despite the fact that 12.1/1 doesn't use an italicized *class-name*).

For example, given:

```
struct Foo;
typedef Foo Bar;
```

then

```
struct Foo { Bar() {} }; // defines Foo's constructor. - 1
```

or instead given

```
struct Foo;
struct Foo { Foo() };
typedef Foo Bar;
```

then

```
Foo::Bar() {}; // defines Foo's constructor - 2
```

or

```
Bar::Bar() {}; // defines Foo's constructor - 3
```

or

```
Bar::Foo() {}; // defines Foo's constructor - 4
```

Any of these should be legal. However nobody seems to accept definitions 2 or 3, MSVC accepts 1, and MSVC, clang, and gcc all accept 4.

Is my analysis correct, and are all these compilers wrong?

Comment: (1) seems to be ruled out by §12.1/3 ("A typedef-name shall not be used as the class-name in the declarator-id for a constructor declaration.")

Comment: You should clarify which version of the standard you're referring to, C++03 (aka ISO/IEC 14882:2003) or C++11 (ISO/IEC 14882:2011); I pray you're not referring to C++98.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield C++11, but I don't think that C++11 has changed anything in this regard.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Currently I'm looking at the document N3337 (draft from January 2012). I've found a version of C++98 which contains the same sentence, so this appears to not have changed (contrary to what http://amalp.blogspot.de/2007/07/typedef-name-as-identifier-of.html claims).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

§12.1/3 of [the working draft N3337 (Feb 2012)](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) states

> A *typedef-name* shall not be used as the *class-name* in the *declarator-id* for a constructor declaration.

This rules out (1).

§12.1/1 seems to use the term "declaration" for both declarations and definitions:

> A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor. […] In such a declaration, […]

(without referring to "definitions" explicitly). I think it's a bit unclear whether this applies to out-of-class definitions or only to inline definitions. If it applies to all kinds of definitions, this would rule out (2) and (3) as well. (4) should be legal in any case.

Comment: @barnes53: I don't know what answer you're reading, but this one doesn't mention *class-head*, and it does mention a constructor declaration... which the code in your comment clearly is not.  He cited a completely different rule from the one you mentioned in your question.  12.1p3 as opposed to 9.1p4.

Comment: @BenVoigt you're right, I skimmed too quickly over the text following "A _typedef-name_ shall not be used"

Comment: I'm not sure I follow on why (2) and (3) are ruled about by this. Where is it said that "declaration" means both declarations and definitions?

Comment: @bames53 : In §12.1/1 it says "*A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor. ... In such a declaration, ...*" so I think all further uses of the word "declaration" in §12.1 are actually referring to this "special declarator".

Comment: @ildjarn I think that's the intended meaning, but the presented syntax (decl-specifiers + class name + parameter list) does not match out-of-class definitions since they contain nested name specifiers rather than unqualified class names.

Comment: @Philipp : Indeed. I think the key here is the formal definition of _declarator-id_: "*nested-name-specifier(opt) class-name*" wherein _nested-name-specifier_ is "*::(opt) type-name ::*". This implies that a typedef may not be used as the _class-name_, but _may_ be used as the _nested-name-specifier_, i.e. concurring with your assessment that `Bar::Foo()` is indeed legal (but is the only legal variation).

Comment: @ildjarn I believe §3.4.3.1/2 is also relevant here: "[…] if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in C, is the injected-class-name
of **C** […]", and I think the injected class name cannot be replaced by a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

Well annoyingly it seems to work in Microsoft C but not other compilers I use.
Especially when desirable in templates.  Maybe I don't know the "standards compliant way" to do this, but It is really useful in templates.

```
template<class T, class T1, ... /* messy, verbose */ >
class MyTemplate {
protected:
    typedef MyTemplate<T,T1, ... /* messy, verbose */ > SimplerName;

    // declare a constructor
    SimplerName(int arg) { ... }
};
class SubClass
    : public MyTemplate<x,y....>
{
public:
    SubClass(int arg) : SimplerName(arg) { ... }
}.
```

Maybe another question perhaps This does not work in GCC, Clang etc, Is there a way to do this in those other compilers ?