# C++ alternate class implementation by rename class with its constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constructor, typedef

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478962/can-typedef-names-be-used-to-declare-or-define-constructors), I can't use my *typedef*-ed typename into constructor.

In my current project, I have to implement a class in two different ways, which can be altered by simply add single macro statement. The code looks like this

```
#ifdef USE_BAR
//declare class Bar in Bar.h and implement it in Bar.cpp
class Bar; 
typedef Bar Foo;
#else /* ~USE_BAR */
//declare class Foo in Foo.h and implement it in Foo.cpp
class Foo; 
#endif
```

`Bar` and `Foo` have exactly same methods, and same constructor overload lists. However with this code, I can't use `Foo* fooInstance = new Foo();` line so far as `USE_BAR` declared because the constructors of `Bar` won't be renamed to `Foo`.
I'm struggling because I want to use a class named `Foo` only, not `Bar`, outside declaration/implementation of these classes, while I also want to distinguish this `Foo` and `Bar` implementation by naming them differently.

Is there any code design pattern to achieve both?

**Edit**: seems like a VC++ issue. And I actually cited macro incorrectly. What I was supposed to write was `ifdef`, not `ifndef`.

Comment: Show, don't tell. What exactly doesn't work? [There's no problem](http://ideone.com/ms3sHW) using a typedef name.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but you seem to be using `Bar` when `USE_BAR` is defined. This seems a bit counter intuitive?? To explain further `#ifndef USE_BAR` checks if `USE_BAR` is **NOT** defined however it is my understanding that you are using `Bar` when `USE_BAR` is not defined??? Could this be the source of your problem??

Answer (score 0):

The rule you cited states:

> A typedef-name shall not be used as the class-name in the declarator-id for a constructor declaration.

This is about declaring the constructor, not *calling* it. That [appears to work fine](http://ideone.com/ms3sHW).

And if for some reason it doesn't, you could always just `#define Foo Bar`.