# Why can't constructors/destructors have alias names in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, alias

Take this class:

```
class Foo {
public:
   using MyType = Foo;

   MyType* m = nullptr; //ok

   MyType* functor() { //ok
      return nullptr;
   }

   MyType() = default; //error
   ~MyType() = default; //error
};
```

Why can you use alias names for members, but not for constructors or destructors?

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Comment: See [Can typedef names be used to declare or define constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478962/can-typedef-names-be-used-to-declare-or-define-constructors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m` is a pointer to an instance of a type, which is aliased. OK.

`functor()` returns a pointer to an instance of a type, which is aliased. OK.

But a constructor/destructor is not itself a type, so you can't use a type alias for them. They must be named after the type they belong to. That is just the way the syntax works

Answer (score 5):

Since this is tagged `language-lawyer`, lets see what the standard has to say.

From [[class.ctor.gen]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor), emphasis added:

> A declarator declares a constructor if it is a function declarator
> ([dcl.fct]) of the form ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause
> ) noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt where the
> ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression, an optional
> attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the
> id-expression has one of the following forms:
>
> (1.1) in a friend declaration ([class.friend]), the id-expression is a qualified-id that names a constructor ([class.qual]);
> (1.2) ***otherwise, in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class or class template, the id-expression
> is the injected-class-name ([class.pre]) of the immediately-enclosing
> entity;***
> (1.3) otherwise, the id-expression is a qualified-id whose unqualified-id is the injected-class-name of its lookup context.

For the subject of why a name alias is not valid to declare constructor, especially (1.2) is of relevance. It states that *the id-expression is the **injected-class-name** [..]*. The latter is defined in [[class.pre]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.pre):

> 1. A class is a type. Its name becomes a class-name ([class.name]) within its scope.
>    [..]
> 2. The class-name is also bound in the scope of the class (template) itself; this is known as the injected-class-name.
>    For purposes of access checking, the injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. [..]

This states very plainly, that the *injected-class-name* is exactly the name used to declare the class in the first place. There is no allowance in the wording for aliases.

---

This follows the same mechanism that you see in a class template:

```
template <typename T> class C { C foo(); };
```

Now, there is no class named `C`, `C` is a template, so you would normally expect to have to say `C<T> foo();`. But as stated in [class.pre], a *class-name* is introduced in the scope of the class definition which refers to the actual type. So, even if there is no class `C` anywhere, the *class-name* `C` can be used as a shorthand for `C<T>` and in the case of constructors and destructors, is the only way to refer to it because their declaration does not allow you to use any type-id, but **only** *class-name*.